# Org-mode: any keyboard shortcut for Latex code?

Tags: yasnippet, keyboard-macros

On p.33 of the [Org-guide](http://orgmode.org/orgguide.pdf) Carsten Dominek writes

> you can use #+LATEX: and #+BEGIN_LATEX ... #+END_LATEX construct to add verbatim LATEX code

Is there a keyboard combination or default snippet that automatically types either of those constructs into the .org file in a similar fashion to `<s` followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> that adds `#+BEGIN_SRC`? (see minute 3:00 in this [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/lsYdK0C2RvQ?t=180))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These shortcuts are called [easy templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html). There are defaults for LaTeX lines (`<L TAB`) and LaTeX blocks (`<l TAB`).

And you can add your own templates by customizing `org-structure-template-alist`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of this [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) code to assist you in entering many Org block templates:

```cl
(defun hot-expand (str)
  "Expand org template."
  (insert str)
  (org-try-structure-completion))
(defhydra hydra-org-template (:color blue :hint nil)
  "
_c_enter  _q_uote    _L_aTeX:
_l_atex   _e_xample  _i_ndex:
_a_scii   _v_erse    _I_NCLUDE:
_s_rc     ^ ^        _H_TML:
_h_tml    ^ ^        _A_SCII:
"
  ("s" (hot-expand "<s"))
  ("e" (hot-expand "<e"))
  ("q" (hot-expand "<q"))
  ("v" (hot-expand "<v"))
  ("c" (hot-expand "<c"))
  ("l" (hot-expand "<l"))
  ("h" (hot-expand "<h"))
  ("a" (hot-expand "<a"))
  ("L" (hot-expand "<L"))
  ("i" (hot-expand "<i"))
  ("I" (hot-expand "<I"))
  ("H" (hot-expand "<H"))
  ("A" (hot-expand "<A"))
  ("t" (hot-expand "<t"))
  ("<" self-insert-command "ins")
  ("o" nil "quit"))
(define-key org-mode-map "<"
  (defun org-self-insert-or-less ()
    (interactive)
    (if (looking-back "^")
        (hydra-org-template/body)
      (self-insert-command 1))))
```

Here's the hint you'll see in the echo area after pressing <kbd><</kbd> from beginning of line:

[image: screenshot]

[See also](https://oremacs.com/2015/03/07/hydra-org-templates/).